# Noty not display message after some clicks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, noty

I'm using noty https://ned.im/noty/

This is my code:

```
<script>
function showNoty() {
var n = new Noty({
        text: "<?php echo $message; ?>",
        type: "error", 
        layout: "top",
        theme:"sunset",
        container: "#content",
        closeWith:[]
    });
    n.show();
}
showNoty();
</script>
```

**Problem:**

Everything works great until do the 6th click on button to display the message.
So, i can do 5 clicks and shows the message correctly, on the +6 click doesn't work anymore.

Someone can give some tips?
Thank you!

Comment: where does `$message` come from? I don't know "noty" so I couldn't be of help there. Check your console and use error reporting. If this is db-related, check for errors and the code you used for it.

Comment: I think you need to check ```maxVisible``` value of Noty. Ref: https://ned.im/noty/#/api?id=api-static-methods . Default maxVisible value is 5 for all queues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to use static method (https://ned.im/noty/#/api?id=api-static-methods)

I solved the problem with:

```
Noty.setMaxVisible(10);
```

Thank you all!